# Exclude property from INSERT command in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an entity with a property which I wish to be readonly - meaning that when I insert this entity to the DB, SqlServer will generate the property's value automatically so I need nhibernate to ignore this property when executing the INSERT command but retrieve it when selecting the entity.

Important note: this property isn't `ID`! I don't want NHibernate to initialize it using generator, SqlServer will do it by itself.

And another note: I use configuration mapping so no fluent mapping solutions please.

Comment: I think it's best if you didn't ask for finely tuned answers including "no fluent mapping solutions" - since as a reader of this question, who uses fluent mapping, I would benefit greatly from the answer including it. The answers aren't exclusively for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is supported. There are two attributes:

```
<property name="GeneratedBySql" insert="false" update="false" />
```

The same could be applied even for reference mapping

```
<many-to-one name="ReferenceGeneratedBySql" insert="false" update="false" />
```

If we want to use Mapping-by-Code we do have the same in places, see:

#### [Mapping-by-Code - Property](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html) *(by Adam Bar)*

Snippet cited:

```
Property(x => x.Property, m =>
{
    m.Column("columnName");
    ...
    m.Update(false);
    m.Insert(false);
```

Comment: Fluent Nhibernate:
Map(x => x.Property)
                .Not.Update();

Comment: `.ReadOnly()` is something else. It ensures you only read data from the DB. It's used to get data generated directly by the DB (and should never even be inserted from outside), normally.

Comment: @Th3B0Y **NO**. Firstly, I would strongly discourage you from learning or even using obsolete and deprecated fluent.. But if you try to understand it - you should learn it carefully. Try to avoid mixing expectations and facts *(which in fact - a different naming in fluent - has caused/brought)*. Mapping is working exactly as I say: ***ReadOnly method ... is just a shortcut for setting both `.Not.Insert()` and `.Not.Update()`.*** [read more](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html). Hope it could help you a bit... and ask a question if you want even more ... ;)

Comment: I didn't understand that from what you wrote before, but it still means what I said. It means the property won't be written anywhere else than the DB or something else that is allowed to write to it.