# NHibernate mapping reference and reference id

Tags: nhibernate

I have simple task. I need map reference to properity and their **ID** to other properity.

If I use this map I get error:

> "Additional information: Invalid index 24 for this
>   SqlParameterCollection with Count=24."

```
    public CityMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        //Map(x => x.AddressID); //This line makes trouble

        References(x => x.Address);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `public virtual int AddressId { get { return Address.Id; } }`?

Answer (score 2):

We can do it for read operation *(I am quite happy to use this approach)*. Just, one of these properties must be **`insert="false"`** and **`update="false"`**.

In fluent it should be like this:

```
...
Map(x => x.AddressID)
   .Insert(false).Udpate(false)
   // or just 
   // .ReadOnly()
   ;
References(x => x.Address);
```

We just have to decide which will be the readonly. Reference? or ValueType? I would make Reference editable, because then all NHibernate built in features will work *(e.g. assign to transient object will properly later insert the just created ID)*

Also check these for some more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26229562/1679310) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30116507/1679310).

Comment: Is Mapping between Objects in nHibernate only possible in fluent-hibernate? Or could I also make this work in 'normal' nHibernate?